# search among values in table

Tags: sql, t-sql, search

We have a parameter Named "@Weight" and This Values in my table:

```
RouteFrom   RouteTo normal      minimum     BP      Q   Value   Price
SYZ         THR     11000.00    99000.00    9.00    100 81.50   9000.00
SYZ         THR     11000.00    99000.00    9.00    250 219.20  7900.00
```

I want single result from these values,If @weight <= breakpoint then show just one of minimum values : 99000 ,if @weight greater than breakpoint and less than min of Value field , then show just one of normal values,else if @weight between one of Qs and Values then show its own price , if less than them and greater than previous row show previous rows price,at the end if greater than every values and qs in table show the price of greater one.

like this:

```
DECLARE @Weight decimal(18,2);
set @Weight = 8;      Price : 99000.00
set @Weight = 10;    Price : 11000.00
set @Weight = 81;    Price : 11000.00
set @Weight = 82;    Price : 9000.00
set @Weight = 150;  Price : 9000.00
set @Weight = 220;  Price : 7900.00
set @Weight = 270;  Price : 7900.00
```

I wrote some query but it show wrong result :(

```
DECLARE @from nvarchar(3);
DECLARE @to   nvarchar(3);

set @from = 'SYZ';
set @to = 'THR';

DECLARE @Weight decimal(18,2);
set @Weight = 220;

select  case
            WHEN @Weight <= BP   then minimum
            when @Weight < value then Normal
            when @Weight >= value AND  @weight <= Q then Price
            WHEN @weight >= Value AND  @Weight >  Q then Price
        end as 'Price'
from    Waybill.RoutePrices inner join Waybill.RoutePriceQ on Waybill.RoutePrices.Id = Waybill.RoutePriceQ.RoutePriceId
where   RouteFrom = @from and routeTo = @to
```

I think,I dont know how to use: case -- end statement
when I  set @weight = 220 result more than one and they are :9000.00 , **7900.00** just **second value** is right(7900.00)
or when I set @weight = 150 results are :**9000.00** , 11000.00 just **first one** is right (9000.00)

Comment: It looks like your `@Weight` values may be eligible for more than one of the `CASE`s

Comment: When you say "wrong result" what do you mean and how would you want it to look?

Comment: for example when I send Set @weight = 220 the result is:9000.00
7900.00

Comment: It must show only 7900.00 for @weight of 220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your commment - is it something like this your after?

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select  case
            WHEN @Weight <= BP   then minimum
            when @Weight < value then Normal
            when @Weight >= value AND  @weight <= Q then Price
            WHEN @weight >= Value AND  @Weight >  Q then Price
        end as 'Price'
from    Waybill.RoutePrices inner join Waybill.RoutePriceQ on Waybill.RoutePrices.Id = Waybill.RoutePriceQ.RoutePriceId
where   RouteFrom = @from and routeTo = @to
)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Price
```

I'm still unsure if this is your request, and if it is - it can be solved in many other ways, can can be solved much more dynamically to provide results for multiple routes and weights using some GROUP BY or PARTITION BY logic